# How can I upgrade my dual boot to a full installation with drive encryption?

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, full-disk-encryption

I have been using elementaryOS with dual boot for quite some time. I first installed eOS as dual boot next to my Windows installation in order to test things and not delete my Windows installation.
But now I am so happy with eOS, that I want to upgrade my dual boot installation into a single boot (only elementary) installation. And is there a way to enable then full drive encryption?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to backup your data, wipe the disk, and reinstall elementary os.  Full disk encryption is available as an option when you reinstall.